# Brinson Attribution - Overweight Underweight

Tags: performance-evaluation, performanceanalytics

I am looking to perform a geometric Brinson type attribution that is able to separate out the effects of underweights and overweight's of individual securities and groups individually.

From an allocation standpoint, this is relatively easy as an overweight/underweight allocations to groups can be determined relatively easily.

I am stuck on how to think about this from a selection standpoint.  I would like to be able to break down selection effect from benchmark relative overweight's and underweights.

Are there any reasonable approaches or papers for this?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. If you have the composition of the sector benchmark, and it overlaps the composition of the sector portfolio, you could calc the (difference in weights for stock i, B vs P) times the return of stock i. This would give you the contribution of each stock to the tracking error in the sector. This is outside the scope of Brinson; it is contribution analysis, not attribution.

Comment: So, yes this makes sense.  I believe I am trying to go outside the scope of Brinson.

I am attempting to determine what contributed to my selection effect within a sector.  Was it primarily overweighting securities which performed well?  Or was it underweighting securities which performed poorly.